# Selectively allow unsafe html tags in Plone

Tags: plone, delicious-api

I'm searching for a way to put widgets from several services (PicasaWeb, Yahoo Pipes, Delicious bookmarks, etc.) on the community site I host on Plone (currently 3.2.1). I'm looking for a way to allow a group of users to use dangerous html tags.

There are some ways I see, but I don't know how to implement those. One would be changing safe_html for the pages editors own (1). Another would be to allow those tags on some subtree (2). And yet another finding an equivalent of "static text portlet" that would display in the middle panel (3). We could then use some of the composite products (I stumbled upon Collage and CMFContentPanels), to include the unsafe content on other sites.

My site has been ridden by advert bots, so I don't want to remove the filtering all together. I don't have an easy (no false positives) way of checking which users are bots, so deploying captcha now wouldn't help either.

The question is: How to implement any of those solutions?

(I already asked that on plone mailing list without an answer, so I thought I would give it another try here.)

Comment: might throw this over to StackOverflow.

Comment: I am not to sure if this is for SO. It seems more specific to configuration.

Comment: This seems like a programming issue. I'd say go to SO.

Comment: I agree that it should go over to SO too.

Comment: I also think this is a SO question.  I've had limited experience with Plone and I'm willing to bet a code modification would be necessary to accomplish this.

Comment: Try one of the Plone support options:  http://plone.org/support

Comment: this is an SO question its programming plone to take these tags, when I get more clout here, I'll vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution (3):

1. Use [TAL portlet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.portlet.tal) to add non-filtered HTML/JS snippets
2. Use [ContentWellPortlets](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.ContentWellPortlets) to show these portlets above or below your content.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Plone 3.2 but there were some tools in the root directory of the *Plone* site when using the ZMI that allowed this.  I can't remember if it was in "portal_transforms" or not, but I think so.  It allows you to specify what tags in the HTML are allowed.  I don't remember if it was something that you could control using the security settings (e.g. role based) or whether it was just a site wide setting.

Sorry for the vagueness but I just figured since you haven't gotten an answer that I'd tell you what I knew (little as that may be).

Answer (score 0):

In Plone Site Setup there is a configlet for HTML Filtering. That may be useful.

PS: SO makes it so hard to help if your points is less than 125. May be I will just stick to the plone users mailing list.

PPS: That should make the answer "more complete"